# Bolt / Visual Scripting running if statement twice?

Tags: unity-game-engine, bolt

So this was working completely fine until today. I start up unity and apparently the gods have cursed me with this if statement running twice??? The variables aren't changing bc they counter eachother out bc its running both sides
[this is after running the function once.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jhx5i.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was messing around with the button that triggered the function to see if I could fix this issue and I deleted the onclick function and then added it back and it worked again. I don't know why this fixed it but it did.